# Returning Ajax Post Data Back to the Success

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I have a very simple form. So simple its scary.  When I run the form, **it returns the data AND the message I require**, however it opens another blank page to display the data.  I have no idea how to return the query data from the php handler file to the success call back. I have tried appending it to the form. I usually do this in codeigniter and its not "all that" hard to do there.

the form and ajax

```
<form method="post" action="/checkipf.php" id="checkip">
<label>Enter the Address</label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="20" name="ip" id="ip" required /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp; 
<div id="display"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#checkip").submit(function(){
var data = $('#checkip').serialize();

$ajax({
    url: "checkipf.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {                        
      $('#display').html(msg).show(1000);   // is this correct?         
      }
    }); 
    return false; 
});
});
</script>
```

The handling php file

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);
    if ($ip = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)){
    $sql = "SELECT `ip`, `total` FROM `spammer` where `ip` = '$ip'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ip = $row['ip'];
        $total = $row['total'];
    }
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "$ip has appeared $total times";

        } else {
            echo "$ip has not been seen";           
        }
    }else{
        echo "IP does not validate";
    }
```

As previously noted, the correct echo in the php file is returned on a blank page. I just cant get it to the success callback. If I run an alert the data shows it is being posted by ajax

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a . in your function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#checkip").submit(function(){
var data = $('#checkip').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "checkipf.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {                        
      $('#display').html(msg).show(1000);   // is this correct?         
      }
    }); 
    return false; 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I must be twice blind, I dont see it nor get an error with firebug. Which line?>

Comment: OMG thank you. Now I feel dumb.  And that my friend is a winner.  TY.

Comment: Haha! No problem. We all make these stupid little errors that we can't see ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="display" style="display:none;" ></div>
```

Then try to show it with the message you receive as you done in your code.

Comment: Nope, I still have the blank page with the return data showing up